# Symfony - Duplicate class definition in cache

Tags: php, symfony, caching, composer-php

I've created a very simple Symfony (3.4) project, with only one api that prints out a static json.

When i run that api for the first time everything works fine, but from second time i got this error:

```
(1/1) FatalErrorException
Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerNameParser
in ControllerNameParser.php (line 24)
```

This is why inside `cache/{env}/classes.php` that class was redefined. In fact, clearing cache turn api to work, but again only for the first time.

How can I solve the issue? I think could be something related to composer.json autoload, here the snip

```
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
        "MyCompany\\TypeBundle\\": "src/MyCompany/TypeBundle"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you have a try at the solutions posted at https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25334 and remove both the include of bootstrap.php.cache and loading a class cache from your app? This is deprecated behaviour in Sf 3.4 according to https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-deprecated-the-classloader-component, and your app should still work

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem. and as i see, the team of symfony is fix that.

try to do this:
in composer.json change version from 3.4.* to 3.3.* and composer update symfony/symfony
than change 3.3.* to 3.4.* back and composer update symfony/symfony

for me it fix the problem. try.